# Serious slowdown due to button row in React/MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI with react for this project.

I have my backend Load items in a mapped out series of cards with props which contain a button row. Said button row is the culprit of the slowdown from what I quickly discovered. This makes sense because its a long pile of code, and the biggest offender of the slowdown appears to be a dialogue popup I prompt to show more information that my initial card does not provide.

Here's a simplified version of my codes logic:

**1. fetch database items in a json. return small card with all props mapped in a grid. Bellow is the return**

```
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="row"
      justify="space-around"
      alignItems="flex-start"
      spacing={2}
    >
      {items.map(x => {
        return (
          <Grid item sm key={`key${x._id}`}>
            <SmallCard
              key={x._id}
              // 18 other properties are assigned here and passed down.
            />
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

**2. in small card is the button row which i pass all my json stuff through with props.**

```
return (
  <Card className={classes.card}>
    <CardActionArea>
      <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.gridItems}>
          <a href={props.GLink}>
            <CardImg imageForCard={props.GPic} />
            <p className={classes.PriceLeft}>{props.GPrice}</p>
            <p className={classes.TitleLeft}>
              {props.GTitle.substring(0, 30)}...
            </p>
          </a>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.gridItems}>
          <a href={props.FriftLink}>
            <CardImg imageForCard={props.FPic} />
            <p className={classes.PriceRight}>{props.FPrice}</p>
            <p className={classes.TitleRight}>
              {props.FTitle.substring(0, 30)}...
            </p>
          </a>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </CardActionArea>
    <ButtonRow
      Key={props.Key}
      // 18 PROPS HERE
    />
  </Card>
```

**3. in button row is the more info button which passes all my props to a dialogue**

```
return (
  <CardActions>
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeOriginal}>
      <ButtonGroup
        variant="contained"
        aria-label="text primary button group"
        type="contained"
        color="secondary"
        size="small"
        className={classes.root}
      >
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <ButtonForInfoCard/>
        <InfoCard
          key={props.key}
          //18 PROPS HERE
        />
      </ButtonGroup>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </CardActions>
);
```

**4. dialogue carries all props which only display the information in smaller components.**

```
return (
  <Dialog
    open={props.open}
    onClose={props.close}
    scroll="body"
    keepMounted
    key={x._id}
  >
    <div className={classes.dialog}>
      <TitleImgLft
        GPrice={props.GPrice}
        GPic={props.GPic}
        GTitle={props.GTitle}
      />
      <TitleImgRt
        FPrice={props.FPrice}
        FPic={props.FPic}
        FTitle={props.FTitle}
      />
      <Notes Notes={props.Notes} />
      <br />
      <VoteCount Likes={props.Likes} Dislikes={props.Dislikes} />
    </div>
  </Dialog>
);
```

I have my components in different folders to organize things But I am still not quite sure what else I can do to speed things up. I'd be happy to show code if it helps but I'm guessing I'm doing some sort of rookie movie that I don't know I am doing.

Here's my file folder layout for reference.

[image: file layout]
All of the code here is simplified and does not show my useState or hooks. All of my components are function based as I was taught to use the newsest methods. Material UI is edited in style sheets an in some cases I use a style override in favor of classes.

Comment: Hard to know without running the code and having the entire picture of what you are doing with the data.
You can use Performance tools to debug your app: https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html

Comment: The tool you linked to appears to be depreciated and they are encouraging me to use the performance tabs in chrome. https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab

Answer (score 0):

It appears the source of my slowdown is the use of themeProvider in materialUI https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider. This color override for some reason really boggged things down for my app. Soon as I removed it and went back to default colors is was flying.